# how to add an apostrophe in php and html

Tags: php, html, symbols

I'm trying to add in the title "What's the benefits?" with the html symbol apostrophe but it breaks the php any ideas?

```
        the_widget( 'zerif_ourfocus','title=Whats The Benefits?&text=Our goal is to bring a winning experience! As a member of a Realta Syndicate you will join a community of like-minded individuals that share the same passion for horse racing and collectively we cheer our horses to the finishing line. At Realta Horse Racing Club we are committed to keeping our members up-to-date on all aspects of training and when our horses are to be declared to run. We offer you the chance to see the progression of your horse from the training gallops to the Parade Ring and from the starter’s flag right through to the exhilarating feeling of being part of the team behind your horse finishing first past the post and into the Winners Enclosure. We believe you cannot beat the value offered in our club membership, Join Us!&link=#&image_uri='.get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/images/Realta-logo-small.png", array('before_widget' => '', 'after_widget' => '') );
```

Comment: You ought to be able to escape it with a backslash, i.e., What\'s The Benefit

Answer (score 2):

Either change your delimiters to double quotes `"` or escape the single quote you want to add `\'`